# How to use another page's control at my current page in windows store application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I want to using another page's control(for example; Frame) my current page in Windows store application.

```
Button mybtnSave = (Button) Master.FindControl("btnSave");
```

This code belongs to Asp.Net but **Findcontrol** unusable in Windows store. I look for to similar code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj, string name)
        where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T && child.Name == name)
                return (T) child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Like this

```
Button mybtnSave = FindVisualChild<Button>(frameobject, "btnSave");
```